# PHP curl and ISIC verification (REST api). How do I make this work?

Tags: php, rest, curl

I would like to verify whether someone has a valid ISIC card, I have written the following code for this Rest API (http://nakoduj.to/_upload/project_files/2015-08-18-12-51-20_DM%20-%20Integration%20Manual.pdf), but it doesn't work, and I have no idea why it doesn't.

```
$data = array(  "cardNumber" => "S123456789000A",
                        "cardholderName" => "John Doe");

$data = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://gts-dm.orchitech.net/api/verifications');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "testdm:testdm");

$result = curl_exec($ch);

if ($result === false) {
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    die('error occured during curl exec. Additioanl info: ' . var_export($info));
}

curl_close($ch);
```

I'm getting false for the $result always. And there is no additional information in $info.

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$data = [
        "cardNumber" => "S123456789000A",
        "cardholderName" => "John Doe",
        ];
$data = json_encode($data);
$header = $request_headers = [
                "Content-Type: application/json"
            ];
$curl_options = [
        CURLOPT_URL =>'https://gts-dm.orchitech.net/api/verifications',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => true,
        CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION => true,
        CURLOPT_FILETIME => true,
        CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT => true,
        CURLOPT_USERPWD => "testdm:testdm"
];
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, $curl_options);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($result);
```

The request header was not sent causing http error code 415 `UnsupportedMediaTypeHttpException` Hence need to add request header, working fine

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong here. First I tried to complete my code, then I tried to copy yours, but it did not work for me. When I'm var_dump-ing the $result, I'm only getting bool(false).

Extra information:
I'm using xampp for running the PHP script.
I have removed the comment line from apache which was in front of the curl dll (I enabled it)

Comment: share a screen shot

Comment: Hmm, I see that it works great for you. But I still can't figure out why it does not work for me. But at least I see that the test environment works, thank you.

Comment: modified curl options see now

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en). Just install it and try to make request with it.
 You'll see the result of your request and than can simply get the request code out. 
You can see 'Code' on your top-right corner below 'save', press it and select your language. For your purposes it is PHP->cURL. And the result will look like this:[image: Postman example]

More about Postman [here](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/)